# java sanitize String, remove / escape all no language characters, various languages such as Chinese, Spanish, etc

Tags: java, escaping, sanitization, sanitize

I am trying to sanitize a string in java (that comes from a comment box) and remove special characters and anything strange like an emoji, the challenge is that the comment can be written in several languages like Chinese, Japanese, Spanish, English ect .
Does anyone know any library or method to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.ç

here an example of the value url:
commentText=Thanks+for+your+review%2C+Francesco+%F0%9F%AB%B6

thist is the part that I would like to remove:
%F0%9F%AB%B6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question in case someone finds it useful
I solved this using a regular expression:

```
String regex = "[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{Z}]";
String commet = "text to sanitize";
comment.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

regexp explanation:

- \p{L} – to allow all letters from any language
- \p{N} – for numbers
- \p{P} – for punctuation
- \p{Z} – for whitespace separators
- ^ is for negation, so all these expressions will be whitelisted